# (Noob) Writing Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python. The Tie option doesn't produce a tie result

Tags: python, python-3.x, thonny

This is my first time posting and using this site, sorry if this isn't the best way to ask.
I have tried researching myself and looking for answers on this forum but each display i find is either a different language to my own or has a different issue.
The issue I'm having is the game runs in terminal just as i would like except when it comes to a tie it doesn't register a tie and just begins a new game "choose your option or type quit to exit" on the next line.
I am using Thonny as my editor and have followed the debugging procedure and it appears it just 'skips' the tie command. how can i fix this or is there some information or documentation you could point me towards to help me understand my issue.
Thank-you

```
    #rock, paper, scissors
import random, sys
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0
print('Let\'s play a game')
print('rock. paper. scissors')

while True:
    print('choose your option or type quit to exit')
    print('%s wins, %s losses, %s ties'%(wins, losses, ties))
    while True:
        playeroption = input()
        if playeroption == 'quit':
            sys.exit() # Quit the program.
        if playeroption == 'rock' or playeroption == 'paper' or playeroption == 'scissors':
            break # Break out of the player input loop.
        
    randomNumber = random.randint(0,2) #selecting computer options
    if randomNumber == 0:
        AIoption = 'Rock'
    elif randomNumber == 1:
        AIoption = 'Scissors'
    elif randomNumber == 2:
        AIoption = 'Paper'       
    if playeroption == AIoption: #player vs computer outcomes
        print('draw, i choose ' + str( AIoption) +'!')
        ties = ties + 1
        continue
    elif AIoption == 'Paper' and playeroption == 'rock':
        print('better luck next time i choose ' + (  AIoption))
        losses = losses + 1
        continue
    elif AIoption == 'Rock' and playeroption == 'scissors':
        print('better luck next time i choose ' + str(AIoption))
        losses = losses + 1
        continue
    elif AIoption == 'Scissors' and playeroption == 'paper':
        print('better luck next time i choose ' + str(AIoption))
        losses = losses + 1
        continue
    elif AIoption == 'Paper' and playeroption == 'scissors':
        print('you win human. I choose ' + (  AIoption))
        wins = wins + 1
        continue
    elif AIoption == 'Rock' and playeroption == 'paper':
        print('you win human. I choose ' + str(AIoption))
        wins = wins + 1
        continue
    elif AIoption == 'Scissors' and playeroption == 'rock':
        print('you win human. I choose ' + str(AIoption))
        wins = wins + 1
        continue
```

Comment: `playeroption == AIoption` is never true because all human options start with a lower-case letter and all computer options start with an upper-case letter. As a side note, you do not need any of those `continue` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been racking my brain thinking i was using incorrect syntax or incorrect formatting

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that your `playeroption` value is every time lowercase and you compare it with an uppercase value so your `if playeroption == AIoption` will never return a true.
If you want to ignore case sensitivity you can do something like:

```
if playeroption.lower() == AIoption.lower()
```

So python will make both your string lowercase and then compare it and it will not matter if the first character is lowcase or uppercase.

You could also add the `.lower()` function to your `if playeroption == 'rock' or playeroption == 'paper' or playeroption == 'scissors':`
like `if playeroption.lower() == 'rock' ...` then the user can enter the his option and it will not matter if the word begins low- or uppercase.